# ionic 3 Location Accuracy Get Error Object(...) is not a function

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have tried follow documentation plugin location accuracy [ionic location accurary](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy/)  and copy paste code in there in a new fresh installer ionic 3

install plugin :

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy
 npm install @ionic-native/location-accuracy`

import in app.module.ts and top component

`import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy/ngx'`;

```
constructor(private locationAccuracy: LocationAccuracy) { }
```

button click methode

```
this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {

 if(canRequest) {    this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
  () => console.log('Request successful'),
  error => console.log('Error requesting location permissions', error)
  );
  }

});
```

but get an error :

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   at LocationAccuracy.canRequest (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:79864:133)

what is the solution?

Comment: same issue for me , no work around

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you installed the plugin for Ionic 4. I did the same.

You just need to install the correct plugin with this:

```
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/location-accuracy@4
```

and the import statement is actually

```
import { LocationAccuracy } from '@ionic-native/location-accuracy';
```

[Here is the ionic 3 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/location-accuracy/)

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct plugin version for ionic 3, work for me:

npm install --save @ionic-native/location-accuracy@4

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

For my experience this only works in ionic 4. I have a ionic 4 App my self with the Location accuracy in there and it works perfectly fine. This wasn't there in ionic 3.